# Excel Formula, script or Macro that takes data from one SHEET 1, search, compare and inputs data to another SHEET 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to create a tracker that will allow me collect attendance data for my employees in Sheet 1. I then want to display that data to track, compare and create some sort of pattern/trending report.

1. Compare an username from SHEET 1/row x with email ID on SHEET 2/row Y
2. If STEP 1 finds a match then compare, format and copy the data to the correct cell based on the Date.

### Sheet 1

```
Username         Instance            Date   
joe@xyz.com        sick              10/1/2020
```

### Sheet 2

```
                                                     Present  Absent
           10/1      10/2       10/3        10/4      Total   Total

NAME        Thu       Fri        Sat         Sun

Joe           1       0           1           2         1       4
```

I have tried `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH` but I am not very familiar with the usage; therefore I am getting lost on choosing the correct cells/columns to compare from one sheet to the other.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Your question is too broad - if you want to avoid it getting closed you'll need to describe *exactly what the problem is*.  What have you tried, and what happened when you tried that?  Also what's with the "javascript" tag?

Comment: You don't have email in `Sheet2`, so how do you anticipate looking up by it?

Answer (score 0):

Id possibly look at how you want to analyse your data. As it seems to be you want to take the data and inject it straight into an absence report of some kind.

Try looking at it this way

1) take your input

2) Validate it (with a vlookup or match)

3) if found write the data to a new line in a data sheet. username, instance, date

This will build a database of sorts that you can then report on.

4) Pivot the data with username for rows, date for columns.  Format the date as you wish depending on granularity.

You can use the sheets change event to pick up the data, validate it and copy it to a db sheet.